# Wordpress form submit with ENTER key is not working

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I am developing a Wordpress theme, and I put the form into searchform.php, and included in my header with:

```
<?php get_search_form(); ?>
```

But, it's working only if I include a button. I tried to put the button and hide it with css, but it's not working. I put the same form in an empty html file, and it worked. I tried to remove the scripts my theme loads, and it didnt work again, so I think the problem is at Wordpress. Wordpress is not letting me submit the search form with ENTER. Does anyone have a solution?

This is the code generated:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="http://localhost/wp/">
    <input type="text" name="s" id="s" class="search" placeholder="Search..." onunfocus="send()">
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the markup generated with get_search_form()?

Comment: I edited the question, posted the code :)

Comment: It used to do this: function send() {
        document.theform.submit() 
    }, but I deleted that because it didnt work, and I just forgot to delete the attribute from the input

Answer (score -1):

A plugin was causing this to happen. It cost me a full day. Thanks those who tried anyways.